# Use css3 transform to create the HTML5 shield logo

Tags: css

I want to create a shield like this:

http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/HTML5-logo.png

This is what I have tried so far but I can not make the bottom area an arrow shape and I can not increase the top area in its height.

How can I do that?

http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/IxEpy

```html
<div id="octagon">
  <div>content</div>
</div>
```

```css
#octagon {
   width: 100px; 
   height: 100px; 
   background: blue;
}
#octagon:before {
   height: 100;
   width: 40px;
   content:"";
   position: absolute; 
   border-bottom: 0px solid blue;
   border-left: 30px solid white; 
   border-right: 30px solid white; 
}
#octagon:after {
   height: 0;
   width: 40px;
   content:"";
   position: absolute; 
   border-top: 100px solid blue; 
   border-left: 30px solid white;  
   border-right: 30px solid white; 
   margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you want to create the shield? for practise?

Comment: not exactly that shield just the shape. Not the inside content.

Comment: Seeing your current progress I'd recommend using SVG for that.

Comment: I know how to do it with 2 divs and a wrapper div around where one div is the square and the other div a css triangle... but I want to try out css3 :)

Comment: ok I found someone doing it before :) http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/html5-css3-logo-updated.html

Answer (score 0):

I made it, not sure how much similar it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yu7f9/

```
#octagon:after {
    margin: 180px 0 0 0;
 }
```

the above part of css is use to increase height for top-area.

Also, check this: http://blog.michelledinan.com/demos/css/triangles/#upIsosceles